# Can't move from one url to another without being logged out using selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\Python36\Drivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
elem2.send_keys('*')
elem3 = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
elem3.send_keys('*')
elem3.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/*/')
```

To log in, the code works fine but from there I'm unsure how it is possible to get to another users page while staying logged in. When I tried to do the driver.get() method it logged me out again

++I have also just found that when I log in and use driver.current_url(), it returns the original page of 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/' rather than 'https://www.instagram.com/'

Comment: How do you know the login code actually works successfully?  Does it redirect you to your own profile page?

Comment: @JohnGordon when I take the last line out it redirects me to https://www.instagram.com/ and shows my home screen. It then logs me out with the last line even if the url is within instagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning:** This is crude code. It's wrong in a lot of senses and you'll have to improve upon it.

Code -

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('location/to/chrome/driver')
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")

elem2 = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
elem2.send_keys('username')
elem3 = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
elem3.send_keys('password')
elem3.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
while True:
    try:
        elem4 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".-Cab_, .bIiDR")
        elem4.click()
        break
    except Exception:
        pass

elem5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input')   
elem5.send_keys("chucknorris")
while True:
    try:
        elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("yCE8d")
        elems[0].click()
        break
    except Exception:
        pass
```

What you'd need to improve upon? Add `timeout`s and `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myElement"))` etc to make your code more robust. Here, if an element is not found in a `while True`, it'll just be stuck, forever, in a limbo. I think you'd not want that. If you do, who am I to stop you. We all are adults here.

**Note:** This does not use `driver.get` but searches for a user ID instead.

Comment: Thank you this all works :) I still don't fully understand how you managed to click a button not in the html of the original URL and where you get the information about the element from?

Comment: @OwenCook I do not understand your question. You mean how did I find elements which were not present when page loaded?

Comment: Yes that’s my question exactly

Comment: I think I want to find the xpath? But I’m not fully sure what an xpath is and how I locate it for an element?

Comment: @OwenCook I waited for the page to load, then inspected the elements that I wanted to click with the help of chrome debugger. There is a tool, it looks like a rectangle with mouse cursor in it. When you find the element, right click on that element, click on copy, then xpath. And if you think the answer helped, please consider accepting it